# Natural Proofs and methods for polylog depth circuit lower bounds

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, co.combinatorics, circuit-complexity, lower-bounds, boolean-functions

I have a question about the following question and its answer.

[Status on circuit lower bounds for polylog-bounded depth circuits](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/status-on-circuit-lower-bounds-for-polylog-bounded-depth-circuits)

In the above question, it is asked about methods to prove lower bounds for poly-log depth boolean circuits.

Jukna's kindful answer suggests two methods: one is matrix rigidity and the other is $t(G)$ which is  the smallest number $t$  such that $G$  can be written as an intersection of $t$  bipartite graphs, each being a union of at most $t$  complete bipartite graphs.

Anyone considering about proofs of circuit lower bounds can not evade the ["Natural Proof"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_proof). In 1994, Razborov and Rudich proved that we *can not*  take any approach satisfying the following three conditions:

1. Constructivity: *hard* property of $f$ which is a boolean function we try to prove its hardness for arbitrary circuit in $\mathcal{C}$ can be computed by poly-time in the size of truth table of boolean function.
2. Largeness: *hard* property of $f$ is easy to find in the sence of random function: the probability which randomly chosen boolean function from the family of all boolean function is at least $2^{-Cn}$
3. Useful: *hard* property can not be dealt with by any circuit in $\mathcal{C}$

My question is:

> Question1: Can bounding the two quantity that is matrix rigidity and $t(G)$ breaking the conditions of Natural Proofs?
>
> Question2: At this moment, is there a method which we guarantee (or may have some hope) that the way is not a kind of natural proofs, if the answer of Question1 is NO?